# Can とか have the same meaning as も?

Tags: grammar

> いいか、危ないぞ。
>   ホントに危ないんだぞ。
>   **イリヤ本人もだけど、部屋の主たる思春期の少年のナイーヴな心臓とかな**

Look, it's dangerous.
Really dangerous.
For Illya too but, among other things the naive earth of the young boy going through puberty who is the owner of the room.

Can とか be used with も to have an inclusive meaning?

Comment: 「ナイーブ」 in Japanese is more like "sensitive" "fragile" than "naïve"

Comment: Oh I see.  I still don't the sentence though.  Could you explain it?

Comment: It's (literally) saying that 部屋の主たる思春期の少年のナイーヴな心臓, as well as イリヤ, is in danger.

Comment: I don't see it.  Shouldn't there be another も after "部屋の主たる思春期の少年のナイーヴな心臓" ?

Comment: 「イリヤ本人もだけど、部屋の主たる思春期の少年のナイーヴな心臓とか**も**な」でもよいと思いますが。。。「Aもだが、Bも危ない」sounds like "both A and B are in danger (A and B are equally important)" whereas 「Aもだが、B**が**危ない」sounds like "B is in danger, though A is in danger, too. (The fact that B is in danger is more important)"

Comment: Yes I knew that and that is why I somehow got confused. According to @naruto it's because he was panicking.  My confusion arose because there was no other particle like が,も etc...

Comment: Yeah, there's no other particle... cos it's not a full sentence... If it was a full sentence it would be either 「～心臓とかも、危ないんだぞ。」 or 「～心臓とかが、危ないんだぞ。」...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can とか used with も to have an inclusive meaning?

Well, yes sometimes, at least in casual conversations. Both can be used to make a non-exhaustive list, but such a mixture of とか and も won't look "well-formed". For example, an excited kid may say something like this:

> 「いろいろ買ったよ、おもちゃとか、ケーキとか、あとね、絵本も！」

But I think this とか in the sentence in question is used primarily for a euphemistic purpose. It's something like "well...", "say...", or "you know..."

The last sentence is a bit roundabout, but it's basically saying "Of course you (Illya) are in danger, but the heart of the owner of this room who is in his puberty (ie, my heart) is also in danger (=almost stopping, because of Illya)!"

Comment: I did not understand that his heart was in danger too at first. 
Shouldn't there be another も after "部屋の主たる思春期の少年のナイーヴな心臓"  ?

Comment: I tought も was needed after every inclusion. Am I mistaken? (Excluding times where you find は、が and other particles like these)

Comment: Yes in a "good" sentence it should be 「…心臓もな」 or 「…心臓とかもな」. But he's half panicked, after all. "Not only you but ... what about my heart!?"